# Is it possible to name windows in emacs

Tags: emacs

I would like to be able to name a window in emacs, and specify that window when opening and creating new buffers.  I've looked through the manual but all I can find is `find-file-other-window`, which doesn't allow me to specify which window to open the buffer in.  Perhaps I'm trying to use emacs in a way it wasn't intended to be used, but what I am trying to achieve is a workspace similar to an IDE:

```
----------------------------------------------
| Project  |  Main editor        | Help Docs |
| Files    |                     |           |
|          |                     |           |
|          |                     |           |
|          |                     |           |
|          |                     |           |
|          |                     |           |
|          |                     |           |
|          |---------------------|           |
|          |  Console/Shell      |           |
|          |                     |           |
----------------------------------------------
```

For example, I would like to have all internal help and python docs open in the right window, and all .py files in the main window by default.  Any ideas?

EDIT:  I should mention that I'm using emacs in no-window console mode.

Answer (score 14):

After extensive googling and head-scratching, I have discovered that what I was looking for is a function called `set-window-dedicated-p`.  Documentation can be found here, for anyone else who happens upon this page:

http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html

Binding a key to this function will cause the selected window to refuse splitting or displaying other buffers.